# Can I apply L'Hopital rule to this limit?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

I have to compute the follow limit:
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} (1+\sin x)^{\frac{1}{2x}}
\end{equation*}
I have taken logarithm and then I have applied L'Hopital rule but in the book says that it's not valid. Any helps?

Comment: What calculations did you perform and what result did you get? What exactly does your book say about this?

Comment: I have done the same that Fred's answer. But, in the book says that L'hopital is not valid in this case. But I think all the hyphotesis of the theorem are true

Comment: Which book are you using?

Comment: Since $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\log (1 + \sin x)}{2x}$$ is, by definition, just $h'(0)$, where $h(x) = \frac{1}{2}\log (1 + \sin x)$ for $-\frac{\pi}{2} < x < \frac{3\pi}{2}$, the book's point may be that using L'hospital's rule would be circular. One can wax philosophically about whether doing that is necessarily circular, but in any case it's silly.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*

Think about the relation with the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{x})^{x} = e$

Answer (score 0):

Since$$(1+\sin x)^{1/(2x)}=\exp\left(\frac{\log(1+\sin x)}{2x}\right),$$all you need to do is to compute the limit$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(1+\sin x)}{2x}.\tag1$$So, consider the function $f(x)=\log(1+\sin x)$. Then$$(1)=\frac12f'(0)=\frac12$$and therefore your limit is $e^{1/2}=\sqrt e$.

Comment: but I want to know why i can't apply L'hopital rule

Comment: First tell us what your answer was and what is it that your book says about this.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=(1+\sin x)^{\frac{1}{2x}}$. Then

$$ g(x):=\ln (f(x))= \frac{\ln (1+\sin x)}{2x}.$$

L'Hospital gives

$$\lim_{x \to 0}g(x)=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ \cos x}{1+ \sin x} \cdot \frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Thus

$$\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)= \sqrt{e}.$$

Your book is wrong !